# Prepared statement with date added by interval as parameter in Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, date, prepared-statement

This works:

```
String query = "select DATE '2016-03-16' + interval '7 days'";
```

But I want to have '2016-03-16' and 7 as parameters in a prepared statement. How to do it?

I tried like this, but it didn't work:

```
String query = "select DATE ? + interval ?";
Object param[] = {"2016-03-16", "7 days"};
```

Comment: Perhaps `select cast(? as date) + cast(?...`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try something like:

```
select to_date(?, 'YYYY-MM-DD') + cast(? as interval)
```

Other option is to use something like

```
select cast(? as date) + cast(? as interval)
```

but it depends on current locale for date conversion

Comment: this solution helped me. Thanks! Out of curiosity though, do you know why the `$1::interval` casting equivalent doesn't work?

Answer (score 4):

If using Java i'd say the cleanest approach would be to use `org.postgresql.util.PGInterval`

Set your query as follows (don't mention 'interval'):

```
String query = "select DATE ? + ?";
```

And add your prepared statement values in this way:

```
stmt.setDate(1, java.sql.Date.valueOf("2016-03-16"));
stmt.setObject(2, new PGInterval(0, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0));
```

In effect, using `PGInterval` represents the whole of `interval '7 days'`